# From where CollectionViewSource's Source gets initialized?

Tags: data-binding, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have created a project in vs 2012 using ItemsPage template.

```
<!-- Collection of items displayed by this page -->
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="itemsViewSource"
        Source="{Binding Items}"/>
```

What do we mean by {Binding Items} here? I see it in an ItemsPage for Windows Store Project. the new ItemsPage has a base class Common.LayoutAwarePage where DefaultViewModel is defined which points to an IMap collection. This collection is not having any Items property so how the Source is pointing to Items here?

Thanks
Kajal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look at the code behind in `LoadState` you'll see:

```
protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
{
    // TODO: Create an appropriate data model for your problem domain to replace the sample data
    var sampleDataGroups = SampleDataSource.GetGroups((String)navigationParameter);
    this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = sampleDataGroups;
}
```

The key to `DefaultViewModel` here is "Items" and that matches the `CollectionViewSource` binding.

Each element of the "Items" collection is a `SampleDataGroup` and then bound to a `GridView` item later in the template.